# Что это за ссылка?

Tags: javascript, html

Заметил что большинство пиратских сайтов для просмотра фильмов хранят все видео по ссылкам такого типа: stream.voidboost.cc/....

Причем на всех сайтах эти ссылки закрыты через blob

Например:https://oxygen.stream.voidboost.cc/47a7d23d4a5beabc7dd3e1a1361a0118:2022082320:50ce8717-2751-4428-918f-a5049355848f/4/3/7/6/5/g1027.mp4:hls:seg-2-a1.ts

а если прописывать после seg-2 выражения v1-,v2-,v3-,.... то получим отрывки длиной в пару секунд.

Можете вкратце обьяснить как все это работает?Как получается разбить видео на огромные кусочки по разным ссылкам? И что это за stream.voidboost ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё довольно прост. Сотня фильмов весит несколько терабайт. Сколько онлайн-кинотеатров? Не каждый может позволить себе арендовать или покупать столь объемное хранилище с дисками на сотни терабайт. Все сайты с пиратским контентом берут фильмы из пары других сайтов, которые размещают на своих серверах эти самые "видео" и позволяют другим пользователям использовать их на своих сайтах, но взамен они вставляют рекламу в видео (фильмы). Когда вы смотрите фильм на пиратском сайте и видите рекламу в плеере - это не реклама сайта, это реклама от сайта партнера, который предоставляет свои услуги (в данном случаи дает возможность просмотра видео). Видео обычно разбиты на "куски" и далее с помощью JS плеера склеиваются воедино. Это нужно, чтобы пользователи не могли скачать фильм просто так.

Comment: и всё таки заменив .ts на .mp4 можно скачать весь фильм)

Comment: Значит на сервере есть целое видео с таким же названием, но другим форматом. Всё индивидуально :)

Comment: В ссылке `https://oxygen.stream.voidboost.cc/47a7d23d4a5beabc7dd3e1a1361a0118:2022082320:50ce8717-2751-4428-918f-a5049355848f/4/3/7/6/5/g1027.mp4:hls:seg-2-a1.ts` уже есть .mp4

Нужно просто удалить с правой стороны лишнее `:hls:seg-2-a1.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Внимательно посмотри на ссылку, которую ты разместил. Если удалить все что после .mp4 (в твоем примере удалить :hls:seg-2-a1.ts) то ты получаешь прямую ссылку на полный файл. качай его любым способом